# C# 4.0 function to check for first four characters in the string

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to validate for valid code name.

So, my string can have values like below:

```
String test = "C000. ", "C010. ", "C020. ", "C030. ", "CA00. ","C0B0. ","C00C. "
```

So my function needs to validate below conditions:

1. It should start with `C`
2. After that next 3 characters should be numeric before `.`
3. Rest it can be anything.

So in above string values, only `["C000.", "C010.", "C020.", "C030."]` are valid ones.

EDIT:

Below is the code I tried:

```
if (nameObject.Title.StartsWith(String.Format("^[C][0-9]{3}$",nameObject.Title)))
```

Comment: That sounds appropriate for a regular expression... what have you tried, and how did it go?

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding regex?

Comment: even if you are avoiding regex, you can access the characters by indexer args like an array, and evaluate from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a regex, for example (written off the top of my head, may need work):

```
string s = "C030.";
Regex reg = new Regex("C[0-9]{3,3}\\.");
bool isMatch = reg.IsMatch(s);
```

Comment: You could shorten the RegEx to `"^C\d{3}\..*"` (off the top of my head).  This should (ideally) match a C followed by 3 numbers and a period at the start of the string.

Comment: @Tim, I need to check the above condition before period not from the starting of string

Comment: @ManojSingh - `^` anchors the RegEx to the start of the string you are using the RegEx against, not to the start of the expression.  Based on your question (**first** four characters of a string) you should use the `^`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"C[0-9]{3}\..*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Strings_in_C_Sharp`
for a quick tutorial on (among other things) individual access of string elements, so you can test each element for your criteria.
If you think your criteria may change, using regular expressions gives you maximum flexibility (but is more runtime intensive than regular string-element evaluation). In your case, it may be overkill, IMHO.